# How to add data in mysql using jsp,js,Java bean, java business class,

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

through client.jsp file i am calling saveClient() mtd for validation---> code--->

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="saveClient();">
```

from now on i will copy paste my all files code with filenames on its top --->

struts.xml

```
<action name="callClient" method="callClient"
            class="org.savvy.tsman.actions.CallActions">
            <result name="SUPERADMIN" type="tiles">cliSa</result>
            <result name="ADMIN" type="tiles">clia</result>
            <result name="EMPLOYEE" type="tiles">clie</result>
            <result name="ACCESSDENIED" type="tiles">AccessDenied</result>
        </action>

        <action name="addClient" method="addClientMethod" 
        class="org.savvy.tsman.actions.ClientAction"></action>
```

hibernate.cgf.xml is configured correctly so i guess no need for pasting that code.

ClientActions.java file

```
package org.savvy.tsman.actions;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.savvy.tsman.beans.ClientBean;
import org.savvy.tsman.business.ClientBusiness;
import org.savvy.tsman.util.AppConstants;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class ClientAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Object>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ClientBean cliBean = new ClientBean();  

    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cliBean;
    }

    public void addClientMethod(){
        PrintWriter out = null;
        JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject resRes = new JSONObject();

        try {

            if (cliBean.getFirstname().equals("") || cliBean.getFirstname().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getLastname().equals("") || cliBean.getLastname().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getClient_No().equals("") || cliBean.getClient_No().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getEmail().equals("") || cliBean.getEmail().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getClient_Type().equals("0")){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getWebsite().equals("") || cliBean.getWebsite().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getContact_No().equals("") || cliBean.getContact_No().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            }else if(cliBean.getAddress().equals("") || cliBean.getAddress().equals(null)){
                resRes.put("Msg", "Field Required : Please enter menu name");
            } else if(ClientBusiness.addClient(cliBean))
                    {
                resRes.put("responseText","success");
                resRes.put("Msg", "sucesssssssssssssssssss : Please enter menu name");
            }
            else {
                resRes.put("Msg","Unknown error : Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            resRes.put("Msg", "Unknown error : Please contact administrator.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            resObj.put("result", resRes);
            System.out.println("Response -> " + resObj.toString());
            out.write(resObj.toString());
            if(out != null){
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

ClientBusiness.java Business file

```
package org.savvy.tsman.business;

import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.savvy.tsman.beans.ClientBean;
import org.savvy.tsman.hibernateUtil.HibernateSessionFactory;
import org.savvy.tsman.pojos.ClientTypesMaster;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.savvy.tsman.pojos.Clients;
import org.savvy.tsman.pojos.User;

public class ClientBusiness {
public static boolean addClient(ClientBean cliBean)
{
Session hSession = null;
Transaction tx = null;
Boolean retBool = false;
try
{
    hSession = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    tx = hSession.beginTransaction();
    ClientTypesMaster ctyp = (ClientTypesMaster) hSession.load(ClientTypesMaster.class, Integer.parseInt(cliBean.getClient_Type()));
    Clients cliPojo = new Clients();
    cliPojo.setFirstname(cliBean.getFirstname());
    cliPojo.setLastname(cliBean.getLastname());
    cliPojo.setClientTypesMaster(ctyp);
    cliPojo.setClientno(Integer.parseInt(cliBean.getClient_No()));
    cliPojo.setContactno(cliBean.getContact_No());
    cliPojo.setEmail(cliBean.getEmail());
    cliPojo.setCreatedBy(Integer.parseInt("1"));
    cliPojo.setModifiedBy(Integer.parseInt("1"));
    cliPojo.setAddress(cliBean.getAddress());
    cliPojo.setWebsite(cliBean.getWebsite());
    cliPojo.setCreatedDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    cliPojo.setModifiedDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

    cliPojo = (Clients) hSession.merge(cliPojo);
    tx.commit();
    retBool = true;
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    retBool = false;
}

return retBool;
}

}
```

Clients.java pojo file

```
package org.savvy.tsman.pojos;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Clients entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */

public class Clients implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer clientid;
    private ClientTypesMaster clientTypesMaster;
    private AdsMaster adsMaster;
    private Integer clientno;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String contactno;
    private String address;
    private String website;
    private Integer createdBy;
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    private Integer modifiedBy;
    private Timestamp modifiedDate;
    private Set jobses = new HashSet(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Clients() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Clients(ClientTypesMaster clientTypesMaster, String firstname,
            String email, Timestamp createdDate, Timestamp modifiedDate) {
        this.clientTypesMaster = clientTypesMaster;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.email = email;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Clients(ClientTypesMaster clientTypesMaster, AdsMaster adsMaster,
            Integer clientno, String firstname, String lastname, String email,
            String contactno, String address, String website,
            Integer createdBy, Timestamp createdDate, Integer modifiedBy,
            Timestamp modifiedDate, Set jobses) {
        this.clientTypesMaster = clientTypesMaster;
        this.adsMaster = adsMaster;
        this.clientno = clientno;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.contactno = contactno;
        this.address = address;
        this.website = website;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.jobses = jobses;
    }

    // Property accessors

    public Integer getClientid() {
        return this.clientid;
    }

    public void setClientid(Integer clientid) {
        this.clientid = clientid;
    }

    public ClientTypesMaster getClientTypesMaster() {
        return this.clientTypesMaster;
    }

    public void setClientTypesMaster(ClientTypesMaster clientTypesMaster) {
        this.clientTypesMaster = clientTypesMaster;
    }

    public AdsMaster getAdsMaster() {
        return this.adsMaster;
    }

    public void setAdsMaster(AdsMaster adsMaster) {
        this.adsMaster = adsMaster;
    }

    public Integer getClientno() {
        return this.clientno;
    }

    public void setClientno(Integer clientno) {
        this.clientno = clientno;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getContactno() {
        return this.contactno;
    }

    public void setContactno(String contactno) {
        this.contactno = contactno;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return this.website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public Integer getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Integer createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Integer getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(Integer modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Timestamp getModifiedDate() {
        return this.modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Timestamp modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public Set getJobses() {
        return this.jobses;
    }

    public void setJobses(Set jobses) {
        this.jobses = jobses;
    }

}
```

ClientBean file

```
package org.savvy.tsman.beans;

public class ClientBean {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String client_Type;
    private String adsMaster;
    private String client_No;
    private String contact_No;
    private String email;
    private String hear;
    private String address;
    private String website;
    private String Userid;



    public String getAdsMaster() {
        return adsMaster;
    }
    public void setAdsMaster(String adsMaster) {
        this.adsMaster = adsMaster;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getClient_Type() {
        return client_Type;
    }
    public void setClient_Type(String client_Type) {
        this.client_Type = client_Type;
    }
    public String getClient_No() {
        return client_No;
    }
    public void setClient_No(String client_No) {
        this.client_No = client_No;
    }
    public String getContact_No() {
        return contact_No;
    }
    public void setContact_No(String contact_No) {
        this.contact_No = contact_No;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getHear() {
        return hear;
    }
    public void setHear(String hear) {
        this.hear = hear;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
    public String getUserid() {
        return Userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        Userid = userid;
    }
}
```

ClientsTypesMaster pojo file

```
package org.savvy.tsman.pojos;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * ClientTypesMaster entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */

public class ClientTypesMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer typeId;
    private String typeName;
    private Set clientses = new HashSet(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public ClientTypesMaster() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public ClientTypesMaster(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public ClientTypesMaster(String typeName, Set clientses) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.clientses = clientses;
    }

    // Property accessors

    public Integer getTypeId() {
        return this.typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(Integer typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public String getTypeName() {
        return this.typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }

    public Set getClientses() {
        return this.clientses;
    }

    public void setClientses(Set clientses) {
        this.clientses = clientses;
    }

}
```

I am using Mysql database and its structure is as follows

I have two table one for client type called client_types_master with 2 columns typeid and typename.

Another table name is clients and has 14 columns in same order as given below
    clientid,clientno,client_type,firstname,lastname,email,contactno,address,website,ads_id,created_By,created_Date,modified_By,Modified_Date

Now the problem is, 
 I am able to login and front end validation is working fine but when i fill all data and click save button it shows alert msg as no error as i have given it in js file but when i click ok for that alert msg box the data is not added to database and the browser will hang on showing please wait.

Comment: Sorry my question is , How to add data in mysql using jsp,js,Java bean, java business class,struts and hibernate?

Comment: I can help you in hibernate part...

Comment: Fine Sir, So do you need me to add hibernate file? And What is this edit suggested means, I am not getting the concept.,

Comment: @mounika are u using xml for mappings ?